# ¿Para qué sirven los archivos tty?

Tags: python

En la documentación de Python me topé con este método para los objetos como:

```
archivo = open('archivo', 'r'); 
archivo.isatty()
```

que retorna `True`/`False` si el archivo es un tty o no. Y me preguntaba

1. ¿Qué es un archivo tty?
2. ¿Para qué se usa un archivo tty?

> file.isatty()
>
> Return `True` if the file is connected to a tty(-like) device, else `False`.
>
> **Note:** If a file-like object is not associated with a real file, this method should *not* be implemented.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file%20flush#file.isatty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La función `file.isatty` (**TTY** viene de [TeleTYpewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) que son teleimpresoras electromecánicas usadas antiguamente para conectarse a las terminales), te dice si el archivo está conectado a un dispositivo (device) de tipo TTY.

En Linux, puedes saber el nombre del archivo conectado a tu `STDIN` (Standard Input) usando el comando `tty`:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/24
```

El archivo `/dev/pts/24` debería de estar conectado a un dispositivo virtual:

```
>>>  archivo = open('/dev/pts/24')
>>>  archivo.isatty()
True
```

En realidad los archivos `/dev/pts/N` son pseudo-terminales, es decir, aquellas que se crean cuando tienes una sesión desde una interfaz gráfica (por ejemplo, usando `gnome-terminal`). Si te conectas a una terminal virtual (las que usas en pantalla completa) usando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, puedes ver que el commando `tty` te muestra otro archivo distinto:

```
$ tty
/dev/tty1
```

El archivo `/dev/tty1` también debería estar conectado a un dispositivo TTY:

```
>>>  archivo = open('/dev/tty1')
>>>  archivo.isatty()
True
```

### ¿Qué es un archivo TTY?

En general, el sistema operativo crea unos archivos que te permiten comunicarte con dispositivos físicos, normalmente estos archivos se encuentran en la carpeta `/dev` y son tratados de forma especial ya que se les permite tener acceso a los drivers. Los archivos TTY son los responsables de mostrar la entrada y salida de información en la terminal (mediante el teclado y el monitor). Puedes ver una lista de ellos usando:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root  tty     5,  0 ene  6 15:36 /dev/tty
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4,  0 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty0
crw------- 1 cesar tty     4,  1 ene  7 08:04 /dev/tty1
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 10 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty10
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 11 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty11
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 12 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty12
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 13 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty13
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 14 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty14
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 15 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty15
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 16 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty16
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 17 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty17
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 18 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty18
crw--w---- 1 root  tty     4, 19 ene  4 06:55 /dev/tty19
crw------- 1 cesar tty     4,  2 ene  7 07:54 /dev/tty2
...
```

### ¿Para qué se usa un archivo TTY?

Pues, como mencioné en la primera pregunta, son usados por el sistema operativo para permitirte "conversar" con dispositivos físicos como el teclado y el monitor. Tal vez esta imagen ayude un poco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Referencias

- [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)
- [What does “TTY” stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for)
- [What is special about /dev/tty? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514735/what-is-special-about-dev-tty)
- [Understanding /dev](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2597)

Comment: Increible la respuesta muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 3):

`tty` es un terminal físico, con teclado y pantalla, o virtual como XTerm. A diferencia de un fichero normal, cada tty tiene unas "propiedades" como tamaño (las dimensiones, anchura y altura), la posibilidad de cambiar los colores, y otras.
En Unix y sistemas análogos como Linux cada terminal (físico o virtual) se conecta al fichero virtual, su propio `tty`. Se pueden encontrar en `/dev/`: `/dev/tty<N>` son para consolas de texto, y `/dev/pts/<N>` para emuladores de terminal como XTerm o Gnome Terminal.

Un programa puede averiguar que sus `stdout` y `stderr` corresponden a un `tty` y activar un modo especial, para p. ej. crear una interfaz interactiva con "ventanas" cómo `Midnight Commander` en Linux/Unix o `FAR Commander` en Windows.

En Python se puede usar así:

```
import sys
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    # escribir en rojo
    esc="\x1B["
    rojo=esc + "0;31m"
    normal=esc + "0m"
    print(rojo + "Hello World!" + normal)
else:
    # escribir normal
    print("Hello World!")
```

Este código escribe el texto "Hello World!" en rojo usando [secuencias de escape ANSI (en inglés)](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ansi_escape_sequences.htm) si se ejecuta simplemente en `bash`, pero con `stdout` redirigido a un fichero, escribe el texto sin caracteres especiales.

Además es posible enviar algo a un `tty` y este `tty` lo recibirá. [write](http://linux.die.net/man/1/write) y otros programas usan esta característica para enviar mensajes a los usuarios.

Comment: Me parece excelente afirmar que el `tty` es una terminal, pero me parece que la pregunta va más dirgida hacía ¿qué es un archivo `tty`(y no solo `tty` a secas) , cómo se diferencia del resto de archivos, cuál es su uso y por qué en `python` se agrega este método a un file? Por lo menos yo veo de esa manera la pregunta.

Comment: opino que para usar Google Translate no hace falta este sitio, se puede hacer directamente en el SO original

Comment: @user3159253 Esta respuesta está escrita en un español muy pobre, ¿es una traducción automática o es simplemente que el español no es tu idioma nativo? En este sitio no aceptamos traducciones automáticas, y además todas las traducciones deben incluir enlace al original.

Comment: Perdóname por favor por mi Español, mi idioma nativo es Ruso. Lo siento, sin practica no sé muchos términos técnicos todavía.

Comment: Si a ustedes les parece inaceptable, puedo eliminar la respuesta completamente. Pero si es posible mejorar el idioma, lo agradecería.

Comment: Dado que no era una traducción automática sino contenido legítimo, he reabierto la respuesta y he corregido los errores gramaticales.

Answer (score 0):

tty es un comando de Unix (también en similares como GNU/Linux) que muestra (escribe a la salida estándar) el nombre de fichero de la terminal de la entrada estándar. Para ejecutarlo, desde un emulador de terminal, se escribe tty y se pulsa Enter.